# Replace NAs based on conditions in R

Tags: r, tidyselect

I have a dataset and I want to replace NAs with empty string in those columns where the number of missing values is greater or equal to `n`. For instance, `n = 500`.

```
set.seed(2022)

synthetic <- tibble(
  col1 = runif(1000),
  col2 = runif(1000),
  col3 = runif(1000)
)

na_insert <- c(sample(nrow(synthetic), 500, replace = FALSE))

synthetic[na_insert, 1] <- NA
```

What I am trying to do and eventually fail:

```
synthetic %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(sum(is.na(.x)) >= 500, "")))
```

What am I doing wrong in this primitive exercise?

Comment: You are aware, that replacing `NA` with `""` in your numeric vector converts it into a character vector?

Comment: @MartinGal yes. Does this condition affect the desirable results?

Comment: No, but you don't have "numbers" anymore, but strings.

Comment: @MartinGal yes, now it's clear why you asked about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `where` with a `purrr`-like function:

```r
library(dplyr)

synthetic %>% 
    mutate(across(where(~sum(is.na(.x)) >= 500), ~coalesce(as.character(.x), "")))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
   col1                  col2   col3
   <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ""                   0.479 0.139 
 2 "0.647259329678491"  0.410 0.770 
 3 ""                   0.696 0.805 
 4 ""                   0.863 0.803 
 5 "0.184729989385232"  0.146 0.652 
 6 "0.635790845612064"  0.634 0.0830
 7 ""                   0.305 0.527 
 8 "0.0419759317301214" 0.297 0.275 
 9 ""                   0.883 0.698 
10 "0.757252902723849"  0.115 0.933 
# ... with 990 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifelse` function:

```
library(dplyr)

synthetic |> 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(
    sum(is.na(.)) >= 500 & is.na(.),
    "",
    .
  ))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
   col1                  col2   col3
   <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ""                   0.479 0.139 
 2 "0.647259329678491"  0.410 0.770 
 3 ""                   0.696 0.805 
 4 ""                   0.863 0.803 
 5 "0.184729989385232"  0.146 0.652 
 6 "0.635790845612064"  0.634 0.0830
 7 ""                   0.305 0.527 
 8 "0.0419759317301214" 0.297 0.275 
 9 ""                   0.883 0.698 
10 "0.757252902723849"  0.115 0.933
```

Edit:

Using `across` and not `mutate_all`:

```
synthetic |>
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ ifelse(sum(is.na(
                  .
                )) >= 500 & is.na(.),
                "",
                .)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
n <- 500
# convert all to character
setDT(synthetic)[, names(synthetic) := lapply(.SD, as.character)]
# find columns with >= 500 NA's
cols <- which(colSums(is.na(synthetic)) >= n)
# fast!! replace all NA in the found columns to ""
for(col in cols) set(synthetic, 
                     i = which(is.na(synthetic[[col]])), 
                     j = col, 
                     value = "")
```